# IPv6-only WireGuard VPN without NAT

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ipv6, wireguard

#### Goal

I'm trying to set up a WireGuard VPN with IPv6 only through which I (a) want to route all traffic and (b) with a server that is accessible from the internet. Since I couldn't even get (a) to work, I'll just try to get that to work, (b) is just for context.

I have a VPS with a globally routable IPv6, `2a03:4000:xx:xx:18d7:b1ef:fe48:7d35/64` (that's what `ip a` tells me) on `eth0`. I'll refer to it with the hostname `vps`. For testing purposes, the server has no firewall, and `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` and
`net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=2`.

Then I also have my device, which also has an IPv6 address, `2001:1715:yy:yy:db2d:ab24:ed3f:39d4/64` on `wlan0` (this should not be relevant information, since this addr will change when I am on another WLAN). It carries the hostname `laptop`.

I want to end up with something like this:

```
Internet <-> vps <-> laptop
```

With IPv4, I'd use NAT, however in IPv6 world, NAT is discouraged. It's hard to find out what to do instead, but if I've read correctly, then I should give another IP address from the `2a03:4000:xx:xx::/64` block the VPS got to the laptop.

#### Setup

So I write these two wireguard configs:

VPS:

```
[Interface]
Address = fc01::1/128 # Shouldn't really matter?
ListenPort = 1935 # This port is open to UDP on most networks
PrivateKey = uLxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxEQ=

[Peer]
# laptop
PublicKey = swxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmQ=
AllowedIPs = 2a03:4000:xx:xx:ffff::3/128 # Is inside the vps' /64 block
```

Laptop:

```
[Interface]
Address = 2a03:4000:xx:xx:ffff::3/128 # The globally routable IP addr of my laptop via the vps
ListenPort = 1935
PrivateKey = yMxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxm8=

[Peer]
PublicKey = pCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzs=
AllowedIPs = ::/0 # Route all traffic through this peer
Endpoint = [2a03:4000:xx:xx:18d7:b1ef:fe48:7d35]:1935
```

I bring them up:

```
[root@vps ~]# wg-quick up wg0
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -6 address add fc01::1/128 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] ip -6 route add 2a03:4000:xx:xx:ffff::3/128 dev wg0

[root@laptop ~]# wg-quick up wg0
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -6 address add 2a03:4000:xx:xx:ffff::3/128 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -6 route add ::/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -6 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -6 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] ip6tables-restore -n
```

... aaaand it doesn't work.

WireGuard doesn't seem to successfully connect. The Laptop shows a connection and counts sent traffic (but 0B received), but the VPS doesn't show a conection.

How does one set up a IPv6-only WireGuard VPN correctly? And if this is correct, why does traffic sent at one end not arrive at the other end of the tunnel?

If more information (pcaps, `ip` outputs, etc.) would be useful, I'll happily amend the question.

Comment: Does your server actually "own" the entire /64 block? (This is just like in IPv4, just because an interface has 192.168.1.5/24 doesn't mean the entire /24 goes to your machine.) While many hosting providers assign  a separate /64 for each server, that's not universal – more simply you could just be on a shared /64 next to all other customers in that datacenter.

Comment: Also, if the /64 is indeed "yours", it's worth finding out whether it is routed to the server, or if it's "on link". There's additional trickery needed to use an on-link address somewhere else than that link...

Comment: @user1686 Yes. I added the IP address `2a03:4000:xx:xx::beef/128` with `ip addr add` to `eth0` and I could ping it through the Internet. And also, I do receive many Router Solicitations on `eth0`, which all are not in my `/64` block.

Comment: Normally there should not be a significant delay (maybe 2 seconds while duplicate address detection is done). If you run `tcpdump -e -n -i eth0 icmp6` and then externally ping *another* address from your /64 (specifically, one that *isn't* actually assigned to eth0 – perhaps the laptop's WireGuard address or just some random address), what do you see on eth0 – do you get Neighbor Solicitation packets for that address or the actual ping/echo packets?

Comment: I don't receive ICMPv6 echo packets (pings), but there are NS packets being sent to search for this IP: `15:21:04.875401 2c:6b:f5:a0:77:c0 > 33:33:ff:40:e9:24, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 86: fe80::22d8:b00:c3ee:ff4 > ff02::1:ff40:e924: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2a03:4000:xx:xx::2340:e924, length 32`.
`

Comment: Nothing wrong with using NAT if the circumstances demand it. It would also make your setup portable (to other IPv6 networks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't working because your server's gateway assumes **the entire /64 is "on-link"**, that is, every address is directly reachable on the same Ethernet segment – so the gateway makes Neighbor Discovery queries for your laptop's MAC address, but won't receive any reply because the laptop isn't on the same link at all.

(Normally the server will not respond on behalf of addresses that are routed somewhere else – it only replies for addresses that are directly assigned to its own eth0 interface.)

To make this work with on-link addresses, you'll need to use "proxy NDP", i.e. actually make the server **provide NDP replies on behalf of the laptop** (and any other address that you're trying to route over the tunnel).

The most reliable way to do this for IPv6 would be to run the `ndpresponder` daemon on eth0. It will listen for Neighbor Solicitation packets and send the correct Neighbor Advertisements.

(Similarly you could use `ndppd` or even the kernel's built-in `proxy_ndp` feature, but those behave *slightly* differently from real NDP replies and sometimes won't pass the anti-spoofing checks that some VPS hosting operators do.)

Ideally, though, the hosting company **should provide you a *routed* prefix** – one where the datacenter gateway is explicitly configured to route everything 'via' your server's primary address. This would also be slightly beneficial to them, as as a single static route would be more efficient than many dynamic neighbor cache entries.

(Unfortunately, many server hosting companies internally use a certain VPS management platform that prevents them from offering routed prefixes – I've heard that it's the fault of SolusVM, which insists on the "flat on-link /48" model.)

---

*Note: This is not IPv6-specific in any way – the same distinction between 'on-link' and 'routed' exists in IPv4, with the only difference being that IPv4 uses ARP instead of NDP. (For example, if your server was in 192.168.1.0/24 on eth0 and you wanted to route 192.168.1.7 to a VPN client, you'd have exactly the same problem and you'd need proxy-ARP to get around it.)*

Comment: Thank you for explaining the problem and mentioning workarounds!

Comment: Is there a way I can check on my own whether the ISP provides a routed prefix?

Comment: @Andreas: If they state that they provide you a prefix _in general_¹, the easy way would be to run tcpdump for a packet capture, filtering for `icmp6`, and then see what happens when you receive pings to various random addresses within that prefix. If the provider is routing the prefix to you, then you'll directly receive the ICMP Echos; whereas if it's an on-link prefix, you'll only receive Neighbor Solicitations for the addresses (and the Echo Requests won't start appearing until something responds to the NS).

Comment: @Andreas: ¹ Keep in mind that just because your address is within a /64 doesn't automatically mean the entire /64 is yours in the first place, routed or not – the provider should explicitly state whether you get the whole prefix to yourself, otherwise it might be shared. On the other hand, if the provider says you have to request a prefix via DHCPv6-PD (typical for home connections, a bit rare for datacenters) then it's safe to assume it'll be routed.